# webservices using php login in json format

Tags: php

```
    using php    webseriver error coming data not received the issue data in json is not displayed please help me out


<?php

        if(isset($_POST['login'])){
                            include 'includes/config.php';

                            $uname = $_POST['uname'];
                            $pass = $_POST['pass'];

                            $query = "SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE email= '$uname' AND password= '$pass'";
                            $res = $conn->query($query);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==1)
            {
                $array = array("success" => "TRUE");
               echo  json_encode($array);
            }
            else
            {
                $array = array("error" => "Login invalid.");
              echo  json_encode($array);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $array = array("error" => "Data not recieved.");
            echo json_encode($array);
        }

        ?>

    In the above code login webservice usign php to display as in json format success but it showing error:data not received please help me out 

The above code in database values is there but it not showing.
```

using php    webseriver error coming data not received the issue data in json is not displayed please help me out
       The above code in database values is there but it not showing.
  using php    webseriver error coming data not received the issue data in json is not displayed please help me out

Comment: echo $_POST['login']; on top of if condition. & check if login contain data or not...

Comment: no not getting any value how should i  post the value

Comment: so because of that if condition not get execute... so check your html 1st

Comment: in this page i did not write html where i want to add html

Comment: from which page u post the login? please  add both pages ...

Comment: this is webservices write i  didnot add

Comment: <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" required/>
 
   <input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN" style="background-color:#33b5e5;"> 
          <a href="driver_register.php">New Register</a>
    </form>

Comment: I think you help this link : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305360/getting-error-in-login-file-using-php-json/44305596#44305596`